# Print PDF To Printer Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, printing

I have an application that writes SSRS reports as a PDF to a file directory and I would like each time a report is added to the folder for it to be printed to a specific network printer.  The reports are generated using the SQL SSRS web service.

This folder and application is on a server and I cannot use Adobes silent printing to accomplish this.  Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up the Win32 Print Spooler API.  You'll have to use platform invoke to call these native functions from C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized I left this question unanswered and wanted to give a followup in case anyone else encounters this problem. I ended up using the code from the answer found here...

[Print a ReportViewer Without Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734277/print-a-reportviewer-without-preview)

I was able to create the reports using my web service and put them into a report viewer and then simply pass the report and the printer I wanted to print to as parameters to the code above and it handled the printing for me. The only thing I did was extend the functionality to accept a printer name as a parameter and use assign that as the specified printer that I wanted to print to.

Here is some sample code in case anyone wants to see the general flow I used.

```
List<ReportParameter> reportparms = new List<ReportParameter>();

ServerReport rpt = new ServerReport();
reportparms.Add(new ReportParameter("param1", param1));
rpt.ReportServerUrl = reportserver;
rpt.ReportPath = myReportPath;
rpt.SetParameters(reportparms);

//I created a class "ReportPrintDocument" for the code from the question linked above.
ReportPrintDocument rdp = new ReportPrintDocument(rpt, myPrinter);
rdp.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = ps.Printer;

if (p.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
{
    rdp.Print();
}
```

There is some other logic here and there but that is the basic idea that will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [sending your document as raw](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) or you might be able to convert your file to a stream and [send it to your printer using TcpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956198/1446086).